# Relating $x$ to $\frac{dx}{dt}$ in a right triangle.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I have a right triangle with sides of $x$ and $y$. I know $y$ is a constant (500) and that $\frac{d \theta}{dt}$ (where $\theta$ is the angle opposite from side $x$) is also constant ($8\pi$ rad/s). I have already found $\frac{dx}{dt}$ for a specified $x$, but the next problem asks me to relate $\frac{dx}{dt}$ to $x$. How do I do this?

Comment: Do *exactly* same thing, but without plugging in a number for $x$ first. If you can't see how to do that and post what you did, we could show you how to do that translation.

Comment: Here goes. First, I noted that  $tan(theta) = x/y$  or  $tan(theta)=x/500$  Thus  $x=500tan(theta)$  $dx/dt=500sec^2(theta)(dtheta/dt)$  Now, in order to finish I would have to get dx/dt in terms of x, but I don't see how to go from sec^2(theta)dtheta/dt to x...

Comment: Well, you already know $d\theta / dt$, so really your question is how to write $\theta$ in terms of $x$. As a shortcut to a simplified result, it would be easier to first figure out how to write $\sec^2 \theta$ in terms of $\tan \theta$. (it's just a shortcut to make simplifying easier: you don't have to use the shortcut)

Comment: I figured it out. I can write $sec^2(\theta)$ in terms of x, y, and the hypotenuse. I know y and the hypotenuse can be written in terms of x by the pythagorean theorem. Plug everything in and you get the answer

Comment: $$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{4πd^2}{250}+1000$$

Comment: what  is   $d$?   $$

Comment: oops... I meant x. My paper had a different variable name on it...  $$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{4\pi x^{2}}{250}+1000$$